# Browser automation for grails application

Tags: grails, browser-automation

Developed a web application using grails framework.Now i want to integrate browser automation in my project. Can anybody suggest me how to integrate the browser automation in grails application?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tools like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/). Since the question is pretty generic, I could not be more specific.